# How to convert floating-point numbers to integer values for comparison with each other?

Tags: matlab, classification, nan, decision-tree, matlab-compiler

I want to classify a dataset by using Decision Tree(DT) to compute the accuracy,  for accuracy computation, we compare the result of DTree with the class labels 1 or 2, but the problem is that DTree function returns floating-point numbers in the order of magnitude 1e3. the result of DT classifier was obtained:

```
DT =
 1.0e+03 *
 1.5311
 1.2482
 3.0774
 1.2482
 1.0627
 1.5311
 2.6613
 3.3919
 1.3951
 1.2482
 3.3919
 1.2482
```

in this link,[mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/511338-why-the-resault-is-always-nan) I attached the Matlab program and function and dataset.

I compared DT(i) (the result of a decision tree) with ytest(i) (the last column of test data that are class labels) to identify where the real result is equal to ideal result for computing the accuracy of the classifier by using TP, TN, FN, FP.

For example, TP(True Positive) when we correctly identified the instance belongs to the class 1 (this is our observation from the result of the classifier) and also the instance's label in the test data is 1 (the ideal result) so one unit is added to TP. By computing the TP, TN, FP, FN we use them in the accuracy formula accuracy=(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FN+FP) that It's range is [0 1] , but ADT=0/0=NaN  because the variables tp_dt, tn_dt, fp_dt, and fn_dt are computed zero.

How can I convert the output of the DTree function to integer values 1 or 2?

DT classifier function is:

```
function ppred=DTree (xtest,xtrain,ytrain)
    DTreeModel=ClassificationTree.fit(xtrain,ytrain);
    ppred=DTreeModel.predict(xtest);
end
```

The program is:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
load colon.mat
data=colon;
[n,m]=size(data);
for a=1:n
   if data(a,m)==0
       data(a,m)=2;
   end
end
S=[ consists of 30 number of columns from the dataset];
data0=data(:,S);
rows=(1:n);
test_count=floor((0.2)*n);
[n,m]=size(data0);
test_rows=randsample(rows,test_count);
train_rows=setdiff(rows,test_rows);
test=data0(test_rows,:);
train=data0(train_rows,:);
xtest=test(:,1:m-1);
ytest=test(:,m);
xtrain=train(:,1:m-1);
ytrain=train(:,m);
DT=DTree(xtest,xtrain,ytrain);
tp_dt=0; tn_dt=0; fp_dt=0; fn_dt=0;
for i=1:test_count
    if(DT(i)==1 && ytest(i)==1)
        tp_dt=tp_dt+1;
    end
    if(DT(i)==2 && ytest(i)==2)
        tn_dt=tn_dt+1;
    end
    if(DT(i)==2 && ytest(i)==1)
        fp_dt=fp_dt+1;
    end
    if(DT(i)==1 && ytest(i)==2)
        fn_dt=fn_dt+1;
    end
end
ADT=(tp_dt+tn_dt)/(tp_dt+tn_dt+fp_dt+fn_dt);
disp('Accuracy');
disp(ADT);
```

Comment: Given that `DT` has floating point values in the order of magnitude of 1e3, why do you compare `DT(i)==1` and `DT(i)==2`? Obviously all those comparisons are false, then your four counts will be all zero, and `ADT=0/0==NaN`.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks, as you said I tried to change some lines' indents, I wrote a hyperlink that I attached the program because I couldn't find attach in this site.

Comment: @ Cris Luengo Thanks, I compared DT(i) (the result of a decision tree) with ytest(i) (the last column of test data that are class labels) to identify where the real result is equal to ideal result for computing the accuracy of the classifier by using TP, TN, FN, FP.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, for example, TP(True Positive) when we correctly identified the instance belongs to the class 1 (this is our observation from the result of the classifier) and also the instance's label in the test data is 1 (the ideal result) so one unit is added to TP. by computing the TP, TN, FP, FN we use them in the accuracy formula accuracy=(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FN+FP) that It's range is [0 1].r but Its result is NaN, I used this classifier function for other programs and It worked well.

Comment: @CrisLuengo By using breakpoints in Matlab, all the variables tp_dt, tn_dt, fp_dt, and fn_dt are computed zero and ADT=0/0=NaN. why are all tp, tn, fp, fn zero?

Comment: `DT(1)` is 1531.1, and other `DT` values are similarly large. When comparing them to 1 or to 2, the result will always be false. This is why all your counts are 0. Your `DTree` function doesn't return values of 1 or 2, it returns floating point numbers in the order of magnitude 1e3. Why? Because of the input data to your script, which you didn't share with us.

Comment: @CrisLuengo great thanks for your useful comment, I attached the colon dataset in this link:https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/511338-why-the-resault-is-always-nan. How can I convert the output of the function to 1 or 2?